# Branding for various communications in the same company

Tags: branding, design-process, identity

I have a question on Branding. My company has different communication platforms from e-newsletters to magazines. We have various names like Talent Times magazine, Innovate e-newsletter, Digest e-newsletter, Impact brochure. Each name has an identity because it caters to different target audiences.

How do I make sure there is a consistent branding throughout? Must I use the same font for every one of them or use the same primary colors?

Answer (score 3):

There can be no definitive answer for this. But looking at those highly varied company names I would say that the branding very well might be totally different for each (as it is for say [Unilever companies](http://unileversg.weebly.com/uploads/2/8/0/9/28096155/1397810582.jpg)).

Like Unilever, you might choose to [add an additional logo](http://cdn.wolffolins.com/api-images/1b751ced73ba10652c6fb1742969c177/Uni_packs_1400x933.jpg?size=659x&version=1421844338) to the various pieces saying "An ABC Company" or such.

If however you think that all the brands at least fall under the same "communications" company remit, you might consider [Envato's approach](http://market.envato.com/?utm_source=envatocom&utm_medium=promos&utm_campaign=market_envatocom_selector&utm_content=env_selector) where they only subtly restyle each site, to keep each site visually similar, and visually recognisable as an Envato site.

Comment: Thanks. However, I do need a tip on how I can somehow bring them all together and knowing that they belong to the parent brand in our communications mainly via eDMs.

Comment: I understand. Reference my point on using a logo for the particular company, and another logo for the "umbrella company" - Or using Envato's approach of styling the different companies with visual similarity.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Will try to see how we can do this without the need to change all the sub-logos.

Comment: No problem, good luck. Please remember to mark my answer correct if it helped :)